# overflow jumbotron background img to navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to overflow `jumbotron` `background` into `navbar` so I can make this, see my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/k42wuu2h/) example.

I have started experimenting with `overflow` but somehow I see that I don't need that, I just removed `navbar` class `navbar-inverse` and that's it, the image just overflow the `navbar` but, this is working on `jsfiddle` but not on my local `index.html`, it's really confusing for me to understand what's happening, so can someone check my code and explain to me why this example work on `jsfiddle` and not into my local project.

Index.html and main.css

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1024/980/city') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Cover Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="bower/bootstrap/dist/css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
              </form>
            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I need to remove `padding-top: 50px;` from the `body` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this jumbotron example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/) from the bootstrap website, you'll see that it downloads a specific file called jumbotron.css to apply the exact style you have. Its content:

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```